# create exe using resource file in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

Am new to vc++. I wanted to create a sample vc++ application with resource file.

This has to be an exe file that launches the windows form that holds a textbox.

I have searched to get a sample application but could not find any help

Please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) provides a lot of [sample applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1370z17c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) including walktroughs that give you a better understanding of the Visual Studio IDE.